# Wildcard replace RegEx in C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I've searched and searched, seen some bits of code that looks like the solution, but it doesn't work. I'm not experienced in the use of Regular expressions and I would like to see what I'm doing wrong here.

```
string line = input.Replace("<td>", ";");
string withoutTabs = Regex.Replace(line, "\t", ";");
string withoutTD = Regex.Replace(withoutTabs, ".*</td>", ";");
```

The code above is trying to replace all of the `<td> </td>` and tabs from a HTML table layout. But it doesn't work, it doesn't remove the tabs nor does it replace the `</td>` tags. The `</td>` tag is usually attached to some text, like this: `text</td>`

I want it to look like this: `text;`

Could someone point out my mistake, or is my regex all wrong and do I need to replace it with something else?

Comment: Use `line = line.Replace(@"\t", ";");`

Comment: `string withoutTabs = Regex.Replace(line, @"\t", ";");`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Why the @ before the `"\t"`

Comment: otherwise it would treat `\t` as escape sequence.

Comment: `string withoutTabs = Regex.Replace(line, "\\t", ";");`

Comment: It still doesn't remove the tabs

Comment: then it's not a tab character try `\\s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to replace the `<td>` as well as `</td>` and tabs with `;`

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"</?td>|\t", ";");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bP2vJ7/1)

Comment: So if I want to add, let's say `<tr>` or `</tr>`, it becomes this: `Regex.Replace(input, @"</?td>|\t|</?tr>", ";");`

Comment: `Regex.Replace(input, @"</?t[dr]>|\t", ";");`, this will replace opening and closing td,tr and tabs with semicolon.

Comment: Thanks, everything works now. I have one question left, how do I replace `<table width="100%">` with regExp?

Comment: Just concatenate the original regex with the substring, but you must escape special chars. `Regex.Replace(input, @"</?t[dr]>|\t|<table width="100%">", ";");`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be:

```
string withoutEndTD = Regex.Replace(withoutTabs, "</td>", ";");
```

Which is actually the same doing:

```
string withoutEndTD = withoutTabs.Replace("</td>", ";");
```

If you meant to get the text (innerText) of any < td > < /td >, then neither RegExp nor string.Replace is the way to go. You can use DOM processing, say with Linq To XML.